# Synchronizing database between offline .mdb file and online .mdb file

Tags: c#, database, database-design, c#-4.0, database-connection

I want suggestions from the experts, I ve tried to find the solution of the concern issue, unfortunately didn't able to find one. I am using the following

- VS 2010
- .NET 4.0
- Windows Forms
- OLEDB, .mdb for storing database

I ve made windows form application already, now i want two copies of a database/.mdb file, one is offline and other is available online, i want to sync both files in case of any changes have been made at either end. I want suggestions in terms of description regarding implementation specially if the components are available to do such sort of job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jet engine has a native synchronisation mechanism, called Microsoft Jet and Replication Objects (MS JRO), which you may want to use. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244889(v=office.12).aspx) is the reference, and have a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258539) for some code samples.

Comment: Thank you it really helped, lemme try it i hope i will be able to do what i want to :)

Answer (score 0):

I posted an article upon on-line off-line database synchronization. here you can find how to synchronize multiple databases (same schema).there should be one master database and others will be updated according to it. you can try this : http://blog.ankitverma.com/2010/03/onlineoffline-database-synchronization/